# jQuery validation - multiple instances of the same error for a single form element

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am looking for a solution where I can have two instances of the same error message for a given input field.

More specifically, I want to insert the error message after the form element, and also append it to the relative label element for that form element.

To make things easier to understand, here is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/smilyanp/uzh38/9/).

See how I have two custom error placements:

```
 errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
     error.insertAfter(element);
     $('#username_label').append(error);
 }
```

However, if you try validating the form, you will see that the error message appears only appended in the label element, and there is not error after the input.

Basically, the second statement overrides the first one.

How can I rectify that and have two error messages for that input, that are both removed when an element is valid, and both shown when an element is invalid?

Comment: You should avoid using `append()` with error messages from this plugin. It has the potential to screw things up so that the plugin can not properly toggle the error message; then you end up with the same error message repeated many times.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to append one jQuery element already in the DOM to another element?](/q/6364633/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the error element. Right now you first insert the error after the input element and then appending it after username.

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    error.insertAfter(element);
    $('#username_label').append(error.clone());
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uzh38/11/